# Can we get View from UIObject class of UIAutomator

Tags: android, testing, android-testing, android-uiautomator

Instead of UIObject class, can we get View class from the UI matching process?

Answer (score 2):

In short, the answer is no. You can not get View class from the UI matching process.

UIAutomator is designed to simulate user actions(touch, swipe, drag, etc.). You're not supposed to invoke any method on **View** directly. And theoretically UIAutomator has provided enough APIs to do any UI operations.